# `gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net` triggers error `armor-keys-failed`

Tags: gnupg, key-server

```
$ gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-key 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                     
gpg: requesting key FDXXXXXX from hkp server subkeys.pgp.net
gpg: DBG: armor-keys-failed (KEY 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX BEGIN
) ->0
gpg: DBG: armor-keys-failed (KEY 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX END
) ->0
gpg: key FDXXXXXX: "XXX XXX <XXXXXX@XXX.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
>>> elapsed time 1m16s

$ gpg --version                                                                                                     
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.19
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

On Mac OS X 10.10.5.  If I download the ASCII-armored key onto my computer and import it with

```
gpg --import pubkey.XXXXXXXXXXX.asc
```

it works correctly.  Any idea why `--keyserver subkeys.pgp.net` does not work?

Comment: It might well be possible a key server is returning corrupted data. Did you try using another one (`--keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net`)?

Comment: It gave the same output.

Comment: Depending on how you installed GnuPG, you might also have GnuPG version 2 available as `gpg2`. Can you also reproduce the issue on other machines? If so, you probably should report the issue on the GnuPG mailing list (which would be a helpful contribution to GnuPG at the same time).

Comment: I installed both gpg and gpg2 via Homebrew on Mac OS X 10.10.5. According to http://superuser.com/questions/655246/are-gnupg-1-and-gnupg-2-compatible-with-each-other they are "compatible".  I'll consider sending the question to gpg mailing list if no more input is given here in the following days.